# else { if {} } and else if {}

Tags: c#, if-statement

Is there any difference between:

```
            else
            {
                if {}
            }
```

and

```
else if {}
```

For example,

```
            var statusValue = "Error";

            if (!canWrite)
            {
                statusValue = "NotOwner";
            }
            else
            {
                if (syncJob.Status == "Idle")
                {
                    statusValue = "InProgress";
                }
            }
```

and

```
            var statusValue = "Error";

            if (!canWrite)
            {
                statusValue = "NotOwner";
            }
            else if (syncJob.Status == "Idle")
            {
                    statusValue = "InProgress";
            }
```

Do the above both codes work in the same way?

Comment: Only in a debug build, and only due to inserting `nop`s so you can break on every line. https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABGgQMIEDeOB1RhyALAQLIAUYAdsAWAJQVU1BYAGYE2AXnEAGHpWyDBAXwCmEAM7LuwiePSyBChWF0BuAwsXnBVmiLHHxqffMMEV65XNdHtDvM+9vY1QzF0C3G2pLMIjsRSA==

Comment: if/else hell, if you write code like first example, from new things is good, but if you need change it later, you will have big problems understand what you need to change without broken functionality

Comment: Are you asking in regard to code compilation or how those statements control the conditions?

Comment: Why you care about this ? for logic is yes. but what point is your confuse?

Answer (score 1):

The two versions of code you showed us do the same thing as each other, but they are not syntactically the same.

When you use the `else if` language element, you can cascade the clauses, something like this:

```cs
if (a == 1) {
  // some code
} else if (b == 2) {
  // some other code
} else if (c == 3) {
  // even more code
} else {
  // still more
}
```

Only one of the compound ( code surrounded by `{`  `}` ) statements inside that example gets executed, guaranteed.

When you nest if within else, you don't get exactly the same thing. And if you write it that way when you want `else if` you'll make your code much harder to read. It's a good way to make your future self hate your present self when you must change or debug your code.

Comment: Did you mean "not semantically the same"?

Answer (score 0):

Consider

```
if (condition1)
    DoA();
else
    DoB();
```

Is exactly equivalent to

```
if (condition1)
{
    DoA();
}
else
{
    DoB();
}
```

I strongly recommend the latter because you are less likely to slip errors into your code doing maintenance when the brackets are there.

So...

```
if (condition1)
    DoA();
else if (condition2)
    DoB();
else
    DoC();
```

Is going to be the same as a version with brackets.

As long as you restrict yourself to *single statements*, you don't need brackets. The brackets demarcate *blocks* of statements, and both `if` and `else` can work equally well with either statements or blocks.

One thing that shakes out of all this is that

```
if (condition1)
    DoA();
else 
{
    if (condition2)
        DoB();
}
else
    DoC();
```

And

```
if (condition1)
    DoA();
else 
{
    if (condition2)
    {
        DoB();
    }
}
else
    DoC();
```

Are exactly equivalent to the previous bracket-free example

Comment: I strongly recommend using brackets **every time**. It’s too easy to introduce a bug without them.

Comment: @stuartd Yes, I agree, as I said in my answer. But if I have an `if else` code structure, then I do it like this `if (cond1) { code1(); } else if (cond2) { code2(): } else { code3(); }`. I don't put brackets like this `... else { if (cond2) { code2(): } } else { code3(); }`. Particularly with repetitive `else if`s  the repetitive pattern makes the code clearer

Answer (score -1):

```
if (!canWrite)
{
    statusValue = "NotOwner";
}
// else is ran if the above is false and the condition is true
else if (syncJob.Status == "Idle")
{
    statusValue = "InProgress";
}


if (!canWrite)
{
    statusValue = "NotOwner";
}
// Runs if the above is false
else
{
    // Runs any code up to this point no matter the code condition below
    // Runs if the first is false and this is true
    if (syncJob.Status == "Idle")
    {
         statusValue = "InProgress";
    }
    // Runs any code up to this point no matter the code condition above
}
```

Syntax wise no, but when it is recompiled you will end up with different code... more jumps